# How can you assign mutliple listeners to a single StreamSubscription?

Tags: dart

This is a valid statement

```
StreamSubscription currentSubscription = querySelector(…).onClick.listen(….).
```

here there is one listener that is assigned to one StreamSubscription.

But when you do a queryselectorAll(..).onClick.listen(..) . You are adding listeners to all the query selected elements.

I noticed that the following statement is also valid.

```
StreamSubscription currentSubscription = queryselectorAll(..).onClick.listen(..)
```

Here, I am assigning a 1 StreamSubscription to a list of elements with onClick listeners. How does this work?

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign multiple listeners to a `StreamSubscription`.

Your 2nd statement doesn't work because `querySelectorAll()` returns a collection and you can't listen to a collection.

Maybe this is what you want:

```
Iterable<StreamSubscription> subscriptions = 
    queryselectorAll(..).map((e) => e.onClick.listen(..));
```

and then later

```
if(subscriptions != null) {
  subscriptions.forEach((s) => s.cancel());
}
```

Comment: That was my understanding as well. Right now with dart 11.1, I am able to do this in my code and it is currently compiling correctly. The code within that listeners are correctly triggering as well.

Comment: You're referring listening to the result of querySelectorAll? In this case I need to try it myself and check what's actually going on.

Comment: Yes. When I do a ss.cancel() on the stream subscription that is assigned multiple listeners, then it seems to have removed all the assigned listeners to it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are listening on the `ElementList`. I can't see from the documentation how that is expected to work, so I guess it is effectively receiving the events of all the elements in the list.

You are still only listening on one stream, the `onClick` stream of the `ElementList`, and the `StreamSubscription` you receive relates to that list.